# How to know the direct link of a website table for HTTPGET

Tags: http, web

I am currently working on some automation thing to retrieve all currency rates in a specific bank website.

It was working before as the website provides the rates in HTML format when I use HTTP GET.

However, it seems that they have changed the way on how they built the website. Now, the HTML doesn't contain the rates. It is from my understanding inside a table.

Is there a way to retrieve the table content from HTTP GET?
Can some one teach me how to access the table contents with a direct link if possible.

Below is the webpage that I got problem with.

https://www.dbs.com.sg/personal/rates-online/foreign-currency-foreign-exchange.page

Answer (score 0):

Seems that they changed their website to fetch data via ajax now. You can use your browsers web developer tools and check the network tab to see that there gets additional data loaded, e.g.

`https://www.dbs.com.sg/flplscsapi/personal/default.page?q=(path:=templatedata/MMContent/RatesSGFX/data/personal/en/fx_rates.xml)&max=10&start=0&format=json&includeDCRContent=true` to get a JSON holding Information about the display name of the current, the image to be displayed as well as a shortcut for the current

`https://www.dbs.com.sg/sg-rates-api/v1/api/sgrates/getSGFXRates` to get a JSON which holds Information about the currency rates.

Comment: thank you. but can you elaborate further how you found out the direct link? i inspect in the rates and check the network but im stuck. i cant find where specifically you found out the direct link.

Comment: i found it now. under the XHR tab in Network.what is XHR btw? im really new to this web thing, but i really wanted to learn.

Comment: XHR stands for [XMLHttpRequest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) which can be used to perform asynchronous HTTP Requests. E.g. declared like so `xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`. This kind of request is used from Javascript to load data from the server. For the Webpage in question, first HTML gets loaded which defined which Javascript sources to include. Then Javascript gets called which requests the data and inserts the data into the HTML page